# What's all this blank space above the question title on mobile?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

It looks like there's a lot of wasted blank space directly over question titles on a question page:

[image]

It's blank the entire row except for the "Ask" button. This seems like a waste of space to me.

Comment: How would making the button full width on smaller devices sound?

Comment: It would sound ideal, maybe even expected/normal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A fix has been merged and will go live in the next build. With certain question titles, with the button floated up to the top right, the wrapping gets insane. There's a better solution, but this isn't it.

Reverted for now!